# Send HTML5 Video as a prop in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to send an HTML5 video as a prop from a parent component to a child component in Vuejs.

Parent Component:

```
    <template>
      <div>
         <video ref="video">
            <source src="@/assets/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
         </video>
         <child-component :video="videoElement"></child-component>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
     export default {
       name: "ParentComponent",
       computed: {
         videoElement () {
           return this.$refs.video;
         },  
       };
    </script>
```

Child Component:

```
    <script>
     export default {
       name: "ParentComponent",
       props: {
         video: Object
       }
     };
    </script>
```

This does't seem to work for some strange reason! How can I send the video as a prop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML video element is not an object. You should instead use `HTMLVideoElement` as a props type in the child component.

Comment: This seems to fix it. Thank you!